# Register Service at Runtime via DI in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a requirement to register a service at runtime as I would only know the type of service at run time and I am going to need it immediately.

So far I am doing it like this:

```
interface IRunTransaction
{
    Task<object?> RunTransaction(ModelPosition model);
}

class AddPosition : IRunTransaction
{
    Task<object?> RunTransaction(ModelPosition model)
    {
    }
}

public async Task<object?> AddPositionToDb()
{
    var position = new ModelPosition
        {
            EmployeeNumber = "01234",
            PositionEmploymentStatus = "01",
            PositionNumber = "123",
            PositionStart = DateTime.Now,
            PositionEnd = DateTime.Now.AddYears(6)
        };

    _serviceCollection.AddTransient<IRunTransaction, AddPosition>();

    using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var transService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRunTransaction>();
        transService.RunTransaction(position); 
        return response;
    };
}
```

I am getting this error:

> No service for type IRunTransaction has been registered.

Comment: You register services once at startup. Then you can use them when you need to.

Comment: Hi, I would only know the type of service I need at run time. There are multiple services using IRunTransaction interface

Comment: If you know the types implementing the service interface, you can use factory.

Comment: But you only compile each class once ahead of time.... So don't register the services via their interface `.AddTransient<AddPosition>();`. Or use generics to tell them apart `.AddTransient<IRunTransaction<Position>, AddPosition>();`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks,  Used generic statement and it still gives same error. If I register in startup file than it works well.

Comment: After adding the registration use the .BuildServiceProvider to get an updated service provider. USe this one to resolve the service.